# Is it possible/OK to generate SSRS RDL file dynamically

Tags: reporting-services

My understanding is that *.rdl files are just XML files with the report definition. How viable would it be to generate that file via a different UI tool (not Visual Studio)? My main concern would be the standard changing all the time and having the adjust code for that. Beyond that, I'm guessing I can find the schema and follow that, or even just create some templates in Visual Studio, examine, and create the code to generate something similar, but dynamic. Then just use some command line tool to push the report to SSRS server. I'd be doing all this in PHP. Any red flags anybody can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can upload whatever report you want, once it meets the RDL format accepted by the SSRS server. I have an experience of making such deploy system, which takes reports, transfroms them (localize, substitute default values, etc.) and then automatically deploy to the server.
There is no problems foreseen, except the two:

- You'll probably need to adjust references to datasource and datasets inside the report XML if you use shared ones.
- AFAIR there is no command-line tool to deploy reports to the server, deploying available through `ReportingServices2010` SOAP endpoint, see more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: FYI, as far as I can tell, you can upload reports to the server using the rs.exe tool. But in the end, I tested a few things and preferred using SOAP anyway.